# Как добавить картинку к ListView ?

Tags: android, listview

Имеется ListView

[image: Imgur]

нужно сделать

[image: Imgur]

Comment: какую картинку: на бекграунде или та, которая в квадрате?

Comment: учтите один маленький нюанс картинку нужно грузить в отдельном потоке асинтаском (иначе она не загрузится) исключение только картинки из ресурсов вашего приложения.

была у меня с этим запара пытался в UI потоке грузить картинку на 4.1.2 в итоге ничего не происходило :)

Comment: [Тут](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/113-urok-54-kastomizatsija-spiska-sozdaem-svoj-adapter.html) можно посмотреть как создавать кастомный адаптер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто в layout добавьте ImageView, задайте нужные размеры и вперед. Так же, кое что можно найти [здесь](http://freehabr.ru/blog/android/2022.html)

Если подгружаете текст и картинки, то, могу посоветовать отличную библиотеку UniversalImageLoader